# MathJax not working, Firefox 36.0.4

Tags: support, mathjax, firefox

[image: MathJax not rendering]

As the screenshot shows, my MathJax is not rendering and there's no word from the console (other than a bunch of probably-irrelevant CSS errors I didn't show). I restarted with add-ons disabled and this did not fix the problem.

Curiously, messing with my account's math preferences on Wikipedia appeared to do something. I didn't catch a screenshot of it, but changing to the setting "MathML with SVG or PNG fallback" caused one title to render correctly and the others to show "math processing error". This did not have an effect on the rendering of the pages, which was still LaTeX markup, and I have not been able to reproduce it since.

Comment: http://www.mathjax.org/ itself is not working currently.

Comment: Now it is again. It has been on and off all morning for me.

Comment: @JDH looks like it's okay now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update 2015/03/30**: [CloudFlare reports](http://www.cloudflarestatus.com/incidents/f0nt7qzwln27) that the issues have been resolved.

Peter from the MathJax team here. Our CDN provider has been experiencing attacks on some of its DNS servers (see also this [thread on the MathJax User Group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mathjax-users/kR6qnNLoiIA/79IfdXOpVbIJ)).

This attack leads to erratic DNS resolution failures. We're sorry for the inconvenience this is causing users and we'll send out an update as soon as we get any news.

Comment: I am also experiencing this problem. I wonder if there is some way to tell MSE to use MathML rendering if implemented by the browser.

Comment: Since SE uses MathJax to convert from TeX input to MathML that wouldn't help.

Comment: Hey thanks for this. I've posted a copy of this over at http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251992/230261; the problem's been coming up here and there in comments, chats, and meta posts over the last few days.

Comment: Thanks for cross posting. Sorry we missed that post last week. That would mean it's been going on a lot longer than we suspected -- sorry about that.

Comment: Possible work-around is to enter www.mathjax.org and cdn.mathjax.org into the etc/hosts file (Windows / Linux) and point them to 162.159.240.204. This seems to do it for me. Obviously this will stop working if they change their IP address.

Comment: Experienced the same problems for a couple of days, for my local PC implementations as well. Which is explained by the fact that the whole [MathJax site](https://www.mathjax.org/) and so any linking to it is unavailable at the moment of this writing.

Comment: updated the post -- the problem should be resolved now.